Get last merged PR in main during GitHub Actions Workflow
Is it possible to get the last merged PR on the main branch inside a workflow?
I want to run test coverage during commit, and fail the PR check if the test coverage is going down. For that I need the coverage from the last merged PR in main.

Normally, the coverage CI test would be run on the PR before merging PR, which you can then set to block merging on failure. Why do you want to run the coverage test after merging?

Each PR will add to the code coverage. I want to save the coverage on the workflow. Let's say PR-1 is merged and has a certain code coverage. PR-1 is the last one merged  and when PR-2 is created I want to run a check that will download the code coverage from PR-1 look at the code coverage for PR-2 and the check will fail if code coverage is going down.

You can do it with GitHub API (or gh cli), for example:
- name: Get last merged PR
  id: get_pr
  run: |
    PR_INFO=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
      "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls?state=closed&base=main&sort=updated&direction=desc")
    PR_NUMBER=$(echo $PR_INFO | jq -r '.[] | select(.merged_at != null) | .number' | head -n1)
    echo "Last merged pr_number: $PR_NUMBER"
    echo "pr_number=$PR_NUMBER" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

Now you can use in the further steps, for example download the Code Coverage report (you need to upload it of course during the workflow):
 - name: Download previous coverage
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: coverage-report-${{ steps.get_pr.outputs.pr_number }}
      path: previous-coverage

